# How do I remove the default dock completely (even from Activities overview) on Ubuntu with GNOME?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

This huge dock appears when I press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key:
[image: THIS HUGE DOCK]

I already have plank installed, I just want others dock to be completely removed, I already run a command to remove the default dock, I don't know what the heck is this appearing here, this is very frustrating.